# Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I have no idea how to do this. Thank you

Comment: Do you know what an eigenvalue and an eigenvector is?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what $\mathcal{M}_2$ is?

Comment: [MathJax guide here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). When you post an image instead of typing the question, you make search algorithm cry.

Comment: @KennyLau I just started to learn it yesterday,that's what i know. Ax=lamder x, eigenvector is not changing its direction but it scales with multiplying A again so we can find Ax easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M_2(\Bbb C)$ is a vector space of dimension $\color{red}4$ over $\Bbb C$, isomorphic to $\Bbb C^4$, with isomorphism $\varphi\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right) = (a,b,c,d)$.

Thus, $t$ can be regarded as a linear transformation with domain and codomain $\Bbb C^4$.

The matrix representation of $t$ is:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&2&0\\
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&-2&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

With $t(\vec v)=A\vec v$ where $\vec v \in \Bbb C^4$.

Thus, the eigenvalues are found by solving the equation $\det(A-\lambda I_4) = 0$.